# Playfair's Axiom for parallel planes instead of lines

Tags: axiomatic-geometry

In three-dimensional space, can Playfair's Axiom:

> Given a line $a$ and a point $P$ not in $a$, there is at most one line in $P$ parallel to $a$.

be “replaced by“ the following axiom?

> Given a plane $\alpha$ and a point $P$ not in $\alpha$, there is one and only one plane in $P$ parallel to $\alpha$.

To make the question precise, can Plaifair's Axiom be proved from the following set of axioms?

1. If a point and a plane have a line in common, the point must lie in the plane.
2. Any two distinct points have one and only one line in common.
3. If two distinct planes have a point in common, they have one and only one line in common.
4. Any line and any point not in this line have one and only one plane in common.
5. Any plane and any line not in the plane have at most one point in common.
6. Given a plane and a point not in the plane, there is one and only one plane in the point having no point in common with the given plane.
7. In every line lie at least two points.
8. There exist two lines having no plane in common.

where **to lie in** is a symmetric binary relation on a set partitioned by the three sorts **Point**, **Line**, **Plane**, “$A$ and $B$ have $C$ in common“ is short for “$A$ lies in $C$ and $B$ lies in $C$“, and lines $a$ and $b$ are *parallel* iff they have a plane but no point in common.

My first guess was yes, but now I'm starting to think Axiom 6 is weaker than Playfair's Axiom, since I can't think of a way to prove it. In case anyone is wondering, this question is not from a book or anything but arose quite naturally while trying to find nice axioms characterizing three-dimensional affine space.

Comment: For the distinction between *at most one* and *exactly one* parallel line, see [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167105/non-equivalent-phrasings-of-playfairs-axiom-which-are-in-use).

Comment: The point here is that I am talking about parallel *planes* instead of lines!

Comment: I can see that, but you also ask explicitly about whether "at most" can be replaced by "one and only one".  As you point out we could define a pair of parallel lines in space.

Comment: It sounds to me like *Given a plane α and a point P not in α, there is one and only one plane *through*  P parallel to α.*

Comment: I just didn't want to introduce multiple words for the single relation of Incidence between points, lines and planes, but of course intuitively one can think of a plane *in* a point as going “through“ it.

Answer (score 0):

Given a plane α and a point P not in α, there is one and only one plane through P parallel to α.

When parallel planes set is defined and a plane and a point on one of the other planes is given,then we have this pair as a unique combination because other planes and other points in the given plane fall off in the selection.

The above is strictly true in Euclidean geometry. There is a set of Euclidean  planes parallel to  α. The situation is the same in non-euclidean geometries as well.

However for non-euclidean geometries ( born out of negation of Playfair axiom, Riemann's categorization into the foundations of  three geometries etc.) imho we need to *at first look to* how non-euclidean parallel planes are defined.

*Elliptic geometry*

Consider a series of concentric sphere manifolds M each each normal to a radial plane normal to a straight line axis of symmetry inhabited by co-tangential great circles of constant but different minimum Clairaut constant radii.

Then for any point $P$ i.e., on one spherical shell/manifold in which  $P$ inhabits there is an infinite set of parallel elliptic planes/spheres in $ \mathbb R^3$ not containing $P$.

*Hyperbolic geometry*

Consider a series of pseudospheres (hyper/hypo varieties) sharing a common radial plane of symmetry and perpendicular to single straight line axis of symmetry. Each pseudosphere is inhabited by unique Chebychev Net lines or asymptotic lines of zero normal curvature and constant geodesic torsion obeying Sine-Gordon equation.  Their uniqueness is due to *two asymptotic parallel lines* to line of symmetry.

Then to any point $P$ there is an infinite set of parallel  planes/pseudospheres in $ \mathbb R^3$ not containing $P$ but containing the Chebychev Nets.

If it makes sense I may upload two images after bounty deadline expires.

Comment: I am not quite sure how your answer relates to my question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: When a parallel planes set is defined and a plane and a point on one of the other planes is given,then we have this pair as a unique combination choice because other planes and other points in the given plane fall off in the selection.

Comment: @ Larry: A unique plane exists throgh a given point $P$ parallel to a given plane $\alpha$... this conclusion has to be axiomatically arrived at.. right?

Comment: No, that is one of my Axioms (Axiom 6). I want to prove Playfair's Axiom from this and the other 7 Axioms. I hope my use of the word “replace“ was not too ambiguous here.

Comment: Considereing context of axioms 1-5 you stated, are Axiom 6 "there one and only one plane through the point having no point in common with the given plane" and "there is one and only one plane in P parallel to α" are equivalent statements? Is the important parallelism  aspect/requirement  fully brought out?

Comment: Yes, by two distinct *parallel planes* I mean just the same thing as two *planes having no point in common*, so the two statements are supposed to be just two formulations of the same Axiom.